# How do i configure my laptop for Hardware Acceleration for the Android Emulator to use KVM? (I use arch linux)

Tags: arch-linux, kvm, android

I am a newbie, and I use Arcolinux (Arch based) and hyprland-Wayland.
So I was installing Android Studio, and then in the installation it asked me to configure hardware acceleration for Android Emulator to enable KVM. But I couldn't and the error it shows is " cannot run program xdg-open: no file/directory exists"

What should I do? I'm a noob, so could anyone please explain me where the problem is?

Also, can I configure hardware acceleration later after the installation of the emulator as well?